# Making a generic factory function with access to static properties

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to refactor out a bunch of repeated code and I've hit a bit of a wall. I have a bunch of model classes that represent different types of nodes on a Neo4j db. The classes have a property `static label: string` that corresponds to the type of Node on the DB. I want to use this label, retrieve the nodes and then create instances of the appropriate type.

I have something like this (simplified for this example) that works:

```
class record {
    public static label: string;
    public id: number;
}

class RecordType extends record {
    label = "Some_DB_Label";

    constructor(id: number) {
        super()
        this.id = id;
    }

}

function DBService(klass) {
    /*  should work for all record subclasses each with different labels */
    let label = klass.label;

    /* use label to make db query gettig
       getting records of type $label */

    // create objects from returned information
    let id = 10 //<- id from db
    return new klass(id)
}
```

The javascript side of this doesn't have any trouble - this code works fine. I can just call: `DBService(RecordType)` and get the objects. But I'm tossing out all type checking.

I would like to add generic typing to `DBService`. I understand that I can use the constructor function in the signature for a generic like this:

`function DBServiceG<T>(klass: { new (id: number): T; }): T`

but then I can no longer access the static property. I could also make the static property a regular property on the instance, but then I would need to create an instance to use it - and I can't create the instance until I've made the DB call.

It seems like this should be possible, but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is

```
function DBService<T>(Class: { label: string, new (id: number): T }): T {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I feel a little silly for not trying something so obvious. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not extremely good with typings but this one was obvious indeed.